# How to make ng-click dynamically added into table from a modal to work? AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, dynamic, compilation

I just received a project which contains angularjs in it, I need to do someting and i don´t now what am I doing wrong since I'm a noob in angularjs matters.

The context:

This is just a part of the whole project, all the angular files in the project are configured with gulp.
I have a html page(page1.html) which has a button and a table, this html is controlled by an ng-controller(controller.js), in the html i have a button with an ng-click function.
This function opens a $uibModal which has its own controller and a templateUrl. the templateUrl is in the html file inside an `<script></script>` tag.
The controller of the modal(controller2) is in the same file as the main controller(controller1)
When the modal opens I see one text input, I enter some text then press the add button, the modal closes and in my main html page one row of the table is added with the entered text in the text input.

The problem:

The table on each row next to the text has 2 buttons with ng-click functions, one for delete an one for edit, when the rows are added from the beginning of the compilation they work fine, but when the rows are dynamically added from the modal they don't do anything. I have read some questions with similar problems where the $compile service do the work, but I do not know how to apply it on this case.

Any help will be enormously appreciated.

The html file

```
<div ng-controller="CreateObsController">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="add-observations.html">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h3 class="modal-title">{{ modalTitle }}</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form class="form-horizontal" novalidate name="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputType" title="Item" class="control-label col-md-2">Item</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                        <input type="text" title="Ingrese Item" id="txtIdObs" class="form-control " value="{{count}}">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="inputType" title="Observation" class="control-label col-md-2">Observation</label>
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <textarea title="Enter observation" ng-maxlength="50" ng-model="observacionAdd" id="observationDetail" class="form-control custom-control " rows="3" style="resize:none" placeholder="Observation" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">            
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" ng-click="tablaObsAddOne()()"
                    button-spinner="isProcesando">
                Add obs
            </button>
        </div>
    </script>


    <script>
        //work but only if the rows are in the html before executing the page.
        function RemoveObservation(idx) {
            var row = document.getElementById(idx);
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        }
    </script>
    <br />

    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="form-horizontal ">
            <div class="panel-heading col-md-11" style="background-color:#2196F3; color:white; max-width: 88%; box-shadow: 1px 5px 20px #ccc;" ng-click="paneCollapseObs=!paneCollapseObs">
                 <span >OBSERVATIONS</span>
                <i class="pull-right fa" ng-class="paneCollapseObs ? 'fa-chevron-down' : 'fa-chevron-left'"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1" align="left">
                <button type="button" title="add observation" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" style="font-size:20px; background-color:#2196F3;" ng-click="AddObservation()">+</button>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" style="float: left; padding-top: 0px; box-shadow: 1px 15px 30px #ccc; max-width: 98%;" ng-hide="paneCollapseObs">
                <br />
                <form class="form-horizontal">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    </div>
                    <div class="container-fluid table-responsive table-DescRec espacio">
                        <div class="row col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <table id="tableObservations" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered table-hover table-parametros ">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class="fondoFila colorLetras">
                                        <th class="col-md-1 col-xs-2 text-center">

                                            <label title="Item">Item</label>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="text-left col-md-9 col-sm-offset-1 ellipsis">

                                            <label title="Observation">Observation</label>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-2">

                                            <label title="Edit">Edit</label>
                                        </th>
                                        <th class="text-center col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-2">

                                            <label title="Delete">Delete</label>
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>

                                </thead>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

the controller file

```
    (function () {
    'use strict';
    function CreateObsController($scope, $rootScope, $compile, $log, $filter, $timeout, $state, toaster, authService, hash,
        $uibModal, uiGridConstants, i18nService, blockUI, $window, $document, RutHelper) {        
        $scope.init = init;        
        $scope.AddObservation = AddObservation;
        $scope.RemoveObservation = RemoveObservation;
        function RemoveObservation(idx) {
            var row = document.getElementById(idx);
            row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        } 
        function AddObservation() {
            $uibModal.open({
                animation: true,
                templateUrl: 'add-observations.html',
                controller: 'ModalAddObsController',
                backdrop: 'static',
                size: 'lg', 
                resolve: {               
                }
            });
        }
        function clear() {
            $scope.paneCollapseObs = true;
        }
        function init() {
            clear();
        }
        $scope.init();
    };
    angular
       .module(configData.nameApp)
       .controller('CreateObsController', CreateObsController);
    CreateObsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$compile','$log', '$filter', '$timeout', '$state',
        'toaster', 'authService', 'hash', '$uibModal', 'uiGridConstants', 'i18nService', 'blockUI', '$window', '$document', 'RutHelper'];

})();

(function () {
    'use strict';
    function ModalAddObsController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, $log, $uibModalInstance, authService, toaster, $window, hash, $document) {
        $scope.modalTitle = 'Observations';
        $scope.tablaObsAddOne = tablaObsAddOne;        
        $scope.addObservaciones = addObservaciones;
        $scope.count = rowCountObservations();

        function addObservaciones() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableObservations");
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
            row.className = "text-center";
            row.id = 'filaObs' + (rowCountObservations() - 1);
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            cell1.className = "col-md-1 col-xs-2 text-center";
            cell2.className = "text-left col-md-9 col-sm-offset-1 ellipsis";
            cell3.className = "text-center col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-2";
            cell4.className = "text-center col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-2";
            cell1.innerHTML = rowCountObservations() - 1;
            cell2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("observationDetail").value;
            cell3.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-ico" ng-click="EditObservacion(filaObs' + (rowCountObservations() - 1) + ')"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px">edit</i></button>';
            cell4.innerHTML = '<button class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-ico" ng-click="RemoveObservation(filaObs' + (rowCountObservations() - 1) + ')"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:24px">delete</i></button>';
            observationDetail.value = "";
            txtIdObs.value = rowCountObservations();
        }
        function rowCountObservations() {
            var x = document.getElementById("tableObservations").rows.length;
            return x;
        }
        function tablaObsAddOne() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableObservations");
            if (document.getElementById("observationDetail").value.length != 0) {
                addObservaciones();
                $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
            } else {
                alert("enter text");
            }
        }
    }
    angular
    .module(configData.nameApp)
    .controller('ModalAddObsController', ModalAddObsController);
    ModalAddObsController.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$timeout', '$log', '$uibModalInstance', 'authService', 'toaster', '$window', 'hash', '$document'];
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trigger insert this will do some changes with DOM the problem is that Angular have no idea that some states are changed. I am not sure in your case but you can try this. The $apply will make angular to know about any changes outside the angular world.

```
function tablaObsAddOne() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableObservations");
            if (document.getElementById("observationDetail").value.length != 0) {
                $scope.$apply(function() {
                   addObservaciones();
                })
                $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
            } else {
                alert("enter text");
            }
        }
```

But why you don't just use "ng-repeat" on your table

```
$scope.data = [
   name: 'test',
   value: 'test',
] // store here your data;
$scope.actionEdit = function($index) {
   //code;
}

$scope.actionDelete = function($index) {
//code;
}

<tbody>
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in data track by $index">
   <td>{{item.name}}</td>
  <td>{{item.value}}</td>
<td><button data-ng-click="actionEdit($index)">Edit</button></td>
<td><button data-ng-click="actionDelete($index)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And here just:

```
function tablaObsAddOne() {
            var table = document.getElementById("tableObservations");
            if (document.getElementById("observationDetail").value.length != 0) {
                $scope.data.push({
                  name: 'test1',
                  value: 'test2'
                });
                $uibModalInstance.close('ok');
            } else {
                alert("enter text");
            }
        }
```

This is just one example of what you can do.

But for more details just read more about angular directives like ng-repeat and others this will make your life easier.